# Get every sub matrix n columns long as column in new matrix in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I'm dealing with very large data sets (hundreds of thousands of columns, 14 rows), and I need to get every sub-matrix n columns long as a column in a new matrix, i.e.

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

becomes

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
3 5 7
4 6 8
```

when n = 2.

What I have right now is

```
n_data_points = size(data1, 1);
small_n = 60;
big_n = size(data1, 2);

new_2 = bsxfun(@(x,y)(data1(x + n_data_points * (y - 1))), (1:(n_data_points * small_n)).', 1:(big_n - small_n + 1));
```

But this method is rather slow. How can I do this with native Matlab operations?

EDIT

So after bench marking some of the methods here and doing some more research, I settled on the following:

```
n = 60;
[m, big_n] = size(data1);
a = zeros((m*n), (big_n - n + 1));
for i = 1:(big_n - n + 1)
    a(:, i) = reshape(data1(:, i:(i + n - 1)), 1, m*n);
end
```

This method takes about 2.3 seconds with a 14 by 387160 matrix, whereas my original method takes about 4.8 and @Divakar's takes about 3.9.

Comment: Shameless plug:  this sort of operation is far easier, and faster, in the `R` language.  If you're going to do large data manipuiation a lot, you might want to consider switching languages.

Comment: Oh believe me, I'd love to. I'm an undergrad doing research, it's not up to me :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) that uses [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) -

```
[m1,n1] = size(data1)  %// Get size of input array data1
out = data1(bsxfun(@plus,[1:n*m1]',[0:n1-n]*m1))
```

Sample run -

```
data1 =
     9     2     8     2     4     9     4
     9     3     3     3     8     3     6
     5     8     9     6     6     7     1
     2     3     4     5     5     7     1
n =
     3
out =
     9     2     8     2     4
     9     3     3     3     8
     5     8     9     6     6
     2     3     4     5     5
     2     8     2     4     9
     3     3     3     8     3
     8     9     6     6     7
     3     4     5     5     7
     8     2     4     9     4
     3     3     8     3     6
     9     6     6     7     1
     4     5     5     7     1
```

Comment: For completeness, you forgot to define `n`... it seems to be fast solution though...

Comment: @kkuilla Well the question states `n` as a parameter. Same with `data1`, which is listed in the question as the input array. Yeah, `bsxfun` seemed like one good option for this problem with it's `built-in: @plus`.

Answer (score 1):

For n=2, it's very simple:

```
new_data=[data1(:,1:end-1); data1(:,2:end)];
```

For n>2 you can loop it (I'm sure it can be done even shortly by `circshift`, or `kron`, etc.):

```
new_data=data1(:,1:end-n+1);
for k=2:n
  new_data=[new_data; data1(:,k:end-n+k)];
end
```

Example:

```
n=3;
data1 = randi(10,2,6)

 7     8     5     5     1     1
 8     2     9     2     7     4



new_data =

 7     8     5     5
 8     2     9     2
 8     5     5     1
 2     9     2     7
 5     5     1     1
 9     2     7     4
```

Comment: Yes, circshift or toeplitz, one or those I guess could be used here too!

Comment: This method is much slower than my method and @Divakar's for large values of n. Perhaps you could provide an example with circshift or toeplitz or kron to demonstrate the potential.